# Replacing capacitors in IPS monitor

Tags: capacitor, monitor

I am completely new to the electronics game, so please excuse any layman's terms.

I'm trying to repair an LG IPS234V monitor that has recently started glitching. Once any video input is attached, but only after about 30-60s, the screen will flash up bright lines every 3s.

I've replaced faulty capacitors in a plasma TV and older LCD screen and guessed it might be the same thing, so I opened up the monitor and can hear similar clicking noises to those previous cases.

The only thing is, the part of the board where I can hear the clicking has none of the bigger electrolytic capacitors I'm familiar with.

There is a disc shaped component, labelled with an overlined 100, that has a small hole in it's side and looks as though it may have leaked - is this just a smaller version of the electrolytic capacitors? If not, what type of component is it?
[image: Section of board that is clicking]

Everywhere I've read has said to use a ESR meter to test a capacitor in board, but is there any way to test it with a bog standard multimeter?

Comment: That looks like an inductor, not a capacitor. If you're hearing clicking from it then that is more likely a symptom of a fault elsewhere in the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

That "100" device is clearly a inductor, probably 100 µH.  No, these things don't leak, and I see no evidence of that in your picture anyway.  It is very unlikely to be the cause of the failure.

The clicks you are hearing probably have something to do with the switching power supply this inductor is a part of, but beyond that it's pretty much impossible to guess further without real information, like a schematic.

Given your level of electronics, ditch it and move on.  It's junk, broken, kaput.

Comment: +1 for "Given your level of electronics, ditch it and move on. It's junk, broken, kaput." Just accept that some expertise is required to be able to repair stuff. And that is the reason why people that **can** repair stuff are well paid.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I don't agree with this advice. It is not a case of junk, broken or kaput. The LG IPS234V has an external power adapter, which is not part of the monitor. So it is extremely likely that a replacement power adapter would have resolved the problem.